# Permission denied on access the webCam only on port 8080 (Jhipster)

Tags: typescript, jhipster

I receive permission denied when I tryed to access the webCam on port 8080. I mention accessing the webCam is working on port 9000 and the project was generated with jhipster (java + angular).
This is my code to access the camera.

```
startCamera(): void {
    if (navigator.mediaDevices && navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia) {
      navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia(this.constraints).then(this.attachVideo.bind(this));
    } else {
      alert('Sorry, camera not available.');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default, microphone and camera access are disabled. You can modify the CSP settings in [`SecurityConfiguration.java`](https://github.com/jhipster/jhipster-sample-app/blob/8ba07644713e61d6b3615965842e06974c6c9761/src/main/java/io/github/jhipster/sample/config/SecurityConfiguration.java#L71) to enable them.

In the call to the `featurePolicy` method, make the below change which will enable microphone/camera access in the page, and in all nested browsing contexts (iframes) in the same origin.

```
- microphone 'none'; camera 'none';
+ microphone 'self'; camera 'self';
```

You can see the other CSP Feature Policy options in the [Feature Policy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Feature_Policy/Using_Feature_Policy) docs